# ngAnimate doesn't work with ngShow/ngHide: ng-hide-add and ng-hide-remove classes are not generated

Tags: ng-animate

I am trying to animate the ng-hide/ng-show directive and for some reasons none of the ng-hide-add*/ng-hide-remove* classes are not generated. ng-animate class is not generated as well.
I do have the 'ngAnimate' as a dependency for my module (if i type "angular.module('ngAnimate')" in Chrome console I get an Object).
I removed the classNameFilter ($animateProvider.classNameFilter(/xyz/)).
What else should I look for? I am working on a huge project and I don't know what other settings/configurations might be in place.
Version of angular used is 1.4.3
Version of angular-animate used is 1.4.3

I debugged ngAnimate and:

- function areAnimationsAllowed always returns false because
- rootElementDetected is always false because
- $rootElement is :
  <!-- uiView:  -->
  instead of 
  <div ng-app="myApp" ui-view class="ng-scope">

Is that a known issue?

Thank you in advance!